# Boost Python example failed twice

Tags: python-3.x, boost-python, visual-studio-2010

Am I alone who tried to use following combination:
boost_1_45_0, MSVC 10, Python31 ?

I have discovered that basic sample from boost (boost_1_45_0\libs\python\example\quickstart\embedding.cpp) Neither compiled (I found how to fix it see below) nor works.
Compile time problem:

```
if (PyImport_AppendInittab("embedded_hello", initembedded_hello) == -1)
  throw std::runtime_error("Failed to add embedded_hello to the interpreter's "
             "builtin modules");
```

I have discovered that correct name is not **initembedded_hello** but **init_module_embedded_hello**. So my first question am I right about this renaming?

The second problem is `SystemError: NULL result without error in PyObject_Call` when importing my declared module:

```
from embedded_hello import *
```

Commenting out importing shows that internal python's modules (like a io) works fine. So the second question what the problem with importing?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is everything built as 64-bit / 32-bit?

Comment: ah okay, I sometimes get weird errors like that, if one thing is built as 64 bit and the rest are 32 bit.

Comment: @GWW did you get some workaround?

Comment: I just made sure everything was compiled with the same architecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use PyInit_embedded_hello instead of initembedded_hello for Python 3. Works for me with msvc9.

Apparently quickstart\embedding.cpp has not been updated for Python 3. Take a look at pyhon/test/exec.cpp, which is similar and up to date.

Msvc10 uses a different C runtime library than Python, which might lead to runtime crashes. The recommended compiler for building Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.1, and 3.2 extensions is msvc9, or a compiler that links against vc90crt.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my question relates exactly to Python3. Is it possible at all to use Python3 under boost?

Comment: @Dewfy: Yes, boost works with Python 3. In the embedded.cpp example you have to use **PyInit_embedded_hello** instead of initembedded_hello